# R: Shiny downloadButton for static content

Tags: r, shiny

I have a static PDF file in my `www` folder, that I would like to link to a UI `downloadButton()`. It seems that the server-side `downloadHandler` needs the `content` option to be populated, and is meant for reactively produced output.

I know that I can link to static content using HTML tags, `tags$a('Download file.', href = 'foo.pdf')` on the UI side.

Any suggestions as to how to put the two together will be helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am guessing you just want a button to show up? You can add `class = 'btn'` to your anchor.
Here is an example showing with `class = 'btn'` and without.

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', 100),
    plotOutput('plot'),
    tags$a(href = 'foo.pdf', class = "btn", icon("download"), 'Download file.'),
    tags$a('Download file2.', href = 'foo2.pdf'),
    downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({ hist(runif(input$n)) })
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste('data-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep='')
      },
      content = function(con) {
        write.csv(data, con)
      }
    )

  }
))
```

To add an icon like the `shiny` function `downloadHandler` has refer to the fontawesome library. For example
here is the icon the shiny function uses http://fontawesome.io/icon/download/. Shiny has a wrapper function `icon` to include these icons.

[image: pic showing btn with icon]

Comment: Hmm, the buttons aren't styled as nicely as the `downloadButton`. Is there some way I can figure out the correct class that applies to those?

Comment: @fgnu Shiny uses the font awesome library for its icons. Shiny has an `icon` function which acts as a wrapper to this library. I have updated the example to compare with the class add to the anchor tag, without the class and the generic shiny downloadHandler.

Comment: I'm trying to show a download button (that calls the server's `output$downloadData`) but from html, ie. I'm not using `ui.R` - do you have any ideas? Here's a post just on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060899/custom-html-with-download-data-button-in-shiny

Comment: Sorry, never mind - I've just answered my own question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060899/custom-html-with-download-data-button-in-shiny/#27698022

Answer (score 9):

May be this will help:

```
content = function(file) {
  file.copy('www/foo.pdf', file)
 }
```

Comment: This works. Just note, make sure the variable file and 'www/foo.pdf' are not the same, otherwise 'www/foo.pdf' will be overwritten.

Answer (score 3):

In the context of `ui.R` and `server.R`:

**ui.R**

```
  downloadButton(
    "statFile",
    "Download static file"
  )
```

**server.R**

```
output$statFile <- downloadHandler(
    filename="example.txt",  # desired file name on client 
    content=function(con) {
      file.copy("file_name_on_server", con)
    }
  )
```