# Custom html with download data button in Shiny

Tags: html, r, download, shiny

I'm wondering how to make the Shiny `downloadHandler` work with a custom html UI.

In my `index.html` I have the following:

```
<a id="downloadproject" class="shiny-download-link shiny-bound-output">export</a>
```

And in the `server.R` I have:

```
output$downloadproject <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "test.csv",
    content = function(file) {
        test_data <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
        write.csv(test_data, file)
    }
 )
```

However, I can't get it working. I've noticed inspecting the source on the demo page: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-download.html that the link there points to a resource:

```
<a id="downloadData" class="btn shiny-download-link shiny-bound-output" href="session/58c63083742fd00d75ac37732eb224bc/download/downloadData?w=299e8cd2e7b56a2507a31ddbe72446fd2ce5d51f5940ea0a" target="_blank">
      <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
      Download
</a>
```

However, I guess that this it to be set by the `downloadHandler` from the server side. My a-tag in however does not get any href at all. Is what I'm looking to do even possible? Am I'm making some mistake here? Any ideas on how to fix this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing - did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I think the A tag is being modified by some javascript. If you just download the HTML source for that (which is in an iframe wrapper) then you don't see the long `href`.

So I further think your custom HTML UI doesn't include the right javascript that adjusts the tag.

I think its done by downloadLinkOutputBinding in shiny.js, line 1402 or thereabouts.

Those demos load a lot of js and css, some of it is clearly crucial!

Answer (score 2):

I've just pasted your html and server.R into a test environment and it works - are you still having this problem?

In particular, it turns out that you can leave out the anchor's `href` tag (according to this post on the [shiny forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/shiny-discuss/download$20button$20html/shiny-discuss/Jt6BR7FlyYQ/kMj5l23Zne8J)).

Also, you only need `class="shiny-download-link` on the button (ie. no need for `shiny-bound-output`).

In most cases you will want to pass the downloadable data from the client to the server, so I'll mention how to do that too (thanks to [this post](http://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/)).  On the server:

```
output$downloadproject <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { 'test.csv' },
    content = function(file) {
        write.csv(input$mydata, file)
    }
)
```

And add some javascript into the html:

```
Shiny.onInputChange("mydata", [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]);
```

Hope that helps.